# php curl 417 - Expectation Failed Post Request

Tags: php, windows, curl, debian, virtual-machine

I want to post my $data array to the *ip* /crontab.php..
sometimes its work like witchcraft. but mostly its fail with the ERROR 417.

The array $data is set in all fields.

VMWare Linux Debian 8.0 reachable!

Here is my code:

```
public function output($data)
{

    printr($data);

    $url = 'http:// <ip-VMWare> /crontab.php';

    $curl = curl_init(); //Error 404
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); //return 1

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Error  404
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); //Error  417

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); //Error  417
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); //Error  417

    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:  ")); //Error  404
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("HeaderName: HeaderValue")); //Error  417

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    print_r($response);


    if($response === FALSE)
    {
        echo 'cURL ERROR: '.$response;
    }

    curl_close($curl);

    exit; //stop the add process (only Testing the cURL)

    return 0;
}
```

```
<?php
//VMWare cronjob.php
echo 'ho';
if ($_POST['Serverip'] === '0')
{echo 'ho';
    echo 'ho';}
print_r($_POST);

?>
```

Comment: image is link in the "enter image discription here"

Comment: Please include __actual__ code - not images.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me on lighttpd/1.4.45 server:

```
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, '1.0' );
```

Hope this helps